# Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am building a website to learn coding and am trying to build a tool where a user clicks on a select/dropdown that contains some category names pulled from database **cat** and then another select will appear with subcategory names pulled from database **subcat**. This is almost exactly like Yelp's (go down to the categories) [like Yelp's (go down to the categories)](http://www.yelp.com/biz_attribute?biz_id=Jsuy0DN6NhILXSkHr6UpCA).

I also made a diagram:

[image]

I already have a category dropdown that is pulling from **cat** database:

```
<p><b>Category:</b><br />
 <?php
  $query="SELECT id,cat FROM cat";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);
  echo"<select name='cselect3' class='e1'><option value='0'>Please Select A       Category</option>";
  // printing the list box select command
  while($catinfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
  echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($catinfo['cat'])."\">".$catinfo['cat']."    </option>";

  }

echo"</select>";
?>
```

And I have a subcat that is pulling from subcat database:

```
<p><b>Subcat1:</b><br />
<?php
  $query="SELECT id,subcat FROM subcat";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);
  echo"<select name='sselect1' class='e1'><option value='0'>Please Select A Category</option>";
  // printing the list box select command
  while($catinfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
      echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($catinfo['subcat'])."\">".$catinfo['subcat']."</option>";

  }

 echo"</select>";
?>
```

How do I make a subcategory dropdown based on what the user clicks on category and make it automatically appear?
Thanks so much for any and all help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would just make put the variables in javascript with php and then use javascript functions.. no jquery or AJAX needed.

However you need to have a foreign key for subcategories no matter what.. ie - For every record in subcat table you need to give it a catid so for referencing...

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','dbname');//set your database handler
  $query = "SELECT id,cat FROM cat";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $categories[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['cat']);
  }

  $query = "SELECT id, catid, subcat FROM subcat";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $subcats[$row['catid']][] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['subcat']);
  }

  $jsonCats = json_encode($categories);
  $jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);


?>

<!docytpe html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      <?php
        echo "var categories = $jsonCats; \n";
        echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
      ?>
      function loadCategories(){
        var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
        select.onchange = updateSubCats;
        for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].id);          
        }
      }
      function updateSubCats(){
        var catSelect = this;
        var catid = this.value;
        var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
        subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
        for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
          subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload='loadCategories()'>
    <select id='categoriesSelect'>
    </select>

    <select id='subcatsSelect'>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will notice i selected catid from subcat as well so that you can relate subcats to cat.. this is necessary

Comment: hey thanks for that! Worked great! How could I get it to do that for three sets of dropdowns just like that?

Comment: Yea no problem.. the third dropdown based on the second drop down I assume?

Comment: Alright I put it up here - http://www.danielpaulomalley.com/stackoverflow/selectFromSelect.php

Comment: I used subsubcat for a table name.. you will need a foreign key in that which references the id for your subcats table

Comment: Some things to consider with 3 selects - when you change select 1 you may want to change select 3 back to no options, you may have some selections with no sub selections so you should check that subcatOptions[x] exists, or javascript may error out trying to access an undefined array

Comment: @dano hihi im interested in the 3 drop down selection but the link you shared is no longer available? Could you please send me the other link for the code? thanks a lot!!

Comment: Generating javascript from php will eventually lead to an unmanageable mess in all but the most trivial applications.  I would advise against this approach.

Comment: I used the example above and it works great. But now, I am having a problem trying to get the value id to process using php, and GET don't seem to be returning the id for categoriesSelect nor subcatsSelect ($cat_id=$_GET['categoriesSelect'];)

Answer (score 3):

Since the data in your Sub-Category drop down is dependent on what is selected in the category, you probably want to use ajax. You can set an event listener on your category drop down and when it changes you can request the data for the subcategory drop down and populate it, there are many different ways to go about it, below is one option (using jquery) to get you started.

```
// warning sub optimal jquery code 
$(function(){

   // listen to events on the category dropdown
   $('#cat').change(function(){

       // don't do anything if use selects "Select Cat"
       if($(this).val() !== "Select Cat") {

           // subcat.php would return the list of option elements 
           // based on the category provided, if you have spaces in 
           // your values you will need to escape the values
           $.get('subcat.php?cat='+ $(this).val(), function(result){
               $('#subcat').html(result);
           });

       }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX, you will want that second bit of code to be a separate php file which you will call via AJAX.  in the callback from the AJAX call, just do (pseudo-code): `someContainingDivOrSomething.innerHtml = responseBody;`.

Note that it's generally a bad idea to do querying within your PHP display files directly (separation of concerns).  There are several other things that could be improved.  However, this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

make this html structure on landing page

```
<p><b>Category:</b><br />
 <?php
  $query="SELECT id,cat FROM cat";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);
  echo"<select name='cselect3' onChange='loadSubCats(this.value)' class='e1'><option value='0'>Please Select A       Category</option>";
  // printing the list box select command
  while($catinfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
  echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($catinfo['cat'])."\">".$catinfo['cat']."    </option>";

  }

echo"</select>";
?>

<div id='sub_categories'></div>
```

make a js function assigned to the category dropdown

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
  $.post('load_sub_cats.php',{catid : value},function{data}
                                             {
                                              $('#sub_categories').html(data);

                                             });

}
```

now in your load_sub_cats.php

```
<p><b>Subcat1:</b><br />
<?php
  $catid = $_POST['cat_id']
  $query="SELECT id,subcat FROM subcat where catid = $catid";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);
  echo"<select name='sselect1' class='e1'><option value='0'>Please Select A Category</option>";
  // printing the list box select command
  while($catinfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
      echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($catinfo['subcat'])."\">".$catinfo['subcat']."</option>";

  }

 echo"</select>";
?>
```

You will need to include jquery to this code work.