# Populate dropdowns from two different tables in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to populate dropdowns from two different tables in the database, which are joined together in a 3rd table using the ids from the first two. I used the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection) as a guide for the dropdowns.

The tables:
courses -- id, title;
classes -- id, title;
classes_to_courses -- coursesID, classesID

The code:

```
<?php
include("global.php");
doHeader();
$currentCourseClass = "SELECT id, title FROM courses";
$rsCurrentCourseClass = mysql_query($currentCourseClass);

while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCurrentCourseClass)) {
$categories[] = array("id" => $get_row['id'], "val" => $get_row['title']);
}

$currentCourseClass2 = "SELECT cl.id as classid, cl.title as classtitle, cr.id as courseid FROM classes_to_courses c2c LEFT JOIN classes cl ON c2c.coursesID = cl.id LEFT JOIN courses cr ON c2c.classesID = cr.id";

 $rsCurrentCourseClass2 = mysql_query($currentCourseClass2);


 while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCurrentCourseClass2)) {
 $subcats[$get_row['courseid']][] = array("id" => $get_row['classid'], "val" => $get_row['classtitle']);
 }
/**/
$jsonCats = json_encode($categories);
$jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);


?>
```

My issue seems to be with the second query, $currentCourseClass2. How do I select the courseid from the joined table classes_to_courses so that my array is set up properly?

Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are receiving, but it looks like your join may be wrong.  In the code snippet, you have:

```
SELECT 
    cl.id as classid, 
    cl.title as classtitle
    cr.id as courseid 
FROM classes_to_courses c2c 
LEFT JOIN classes cl ON c2c.coursesID = cl.id 
LEFT JOIN courses cr ON c2c.classesID = cr.id";
```

So you are trying to join the classes table using the c2c.coursesID, and vice-versa for the courses table.

Instead, shouldn't you be joining the classes table based on the c2c.classesID and the courses table on the c2c.coursesID?

```
SELECT 
    cl.id as classid, 
    cl.title as classtitle
    cr.id as courseid 
FROM classes_to_courses c2c 
LEFT JOIN classes cl ON c2c.classesID = cl.id 
LEFT JOIN courses cr ON c2c.coursesID = cr.id";
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I can't believe I missed that. I've been banging my head on this for the last day. Thank you so much!