# How to Make Selection from Drop Down List Based on Previous Selection?

Tags: java, php, jquery, ajax

To make a simple illustration, assuming that I have a table in database which named as category and it consists only two columns which are cat_id and cat_description. Now, the question is how to make a drop down list that shows the cat_id and then the second drop down list will show the cat_description which is matched with the cat_id selected. I have referred to the answer as in 
[Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection)

However it doesn't helps out or perhaps it's too complicating for me t= understand the coding as I am totally new in web languages and the following is my coding

```
<html>
 <body>
  <?php

 // attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=name user=user");
      if (!$dbh) {
     die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
 }

 // execute query
 $sql = "SELECT cat_id FROM category";
 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
     die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }

 echo "<select cat_id='category'>";
 while ($select_query_array =   pg_fetch_array($result) )
 {
    echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["cat_id"])."</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";


 $sql2 = "SELECT cat_description FROM category WHERE category.cat_id = cat_id previously selected";
 $result2 = pg_query($dbh, $sql2);
 echo "<select cat_description='category'>";
 while ($select_query_array =   pg_fetch_array($result2) )
 {
    echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["cat_description"])."</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";

 // free memory
 pg_free_result($result);

 // close connection
 pg_close($dbh);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

From many examples that I tried to look into most of them are related to ajax or java that I really know nothing about them. So if possible I would like to make it in a simplest form like using a second php page but I don't know how to use the selected value of first page in the second page. Ajax/Java is acceptable as I know it shall make life easier just maybe you guys could give a very simple yet complete coding so that I can understand what actually running. thanks in advance for all the helps!!

Comment: This is not Java code. In Java however, you would register an ItemListener to track the changes in the first then call a method to repopulate the second. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Better Populate both combo box if not too big...

Cat ID Combo Box

```
<option 'cat_id'>cat_id</option>
```

Cat Description Combo Box

```
<option 'cat_id'>cat_Desc</option>
```

And Set Default value to "",

Add Javascript onChange() function to "`Cat ID Combo Box`" to get value and set it to the "`Cat Description Combo Box`" value.

And if You want to populate Second Combo box from database then you need to use `AJAX` for populating without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get category id from dropdown of category 
The url will be like this

```
http://localhost/test/cat_id.php?cat_id=5
```

Get the id from url 
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id']; 
Then write a query like

```
select * from category where cat_id=".$cat_id."
```

You will get the description with that query.
Show that data in the second dropdown