# creating a drop down list based on a selection from another drop down list

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a form with several drop down lists.  I want to create a second drop down list based on the selection in the first drop down list.

My data is static, so is javascript the best way to make this work?

Comment: Yes Javascript will be needed unless you're ok with the first list changing causing a page reload. Have you tried any Javascript to accomplish this yet? Can you post things you've tried? Or even the `html` snippets?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the 'best' way to do something. You can do this javascript, php etc..
There was a similar question about the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection). That should solve your question.