# Updating second multi select dropdown based on first multi select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

Help!  I used this code to get 2 dropdowns working so that the second populates with the subcategories based on the selection from the first.

[Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection)

It works fine for single select dropdowns but I need to be able to select multiple items from the first dropdown and have it show the subcategories belonging to all of the selected items from the first.

Currently when an additional item is selected in the first dropdown, the 2nd updates to only show the subcategories for the latest selected item, presumably because it's doing the 'new Option' bit of the function.  How do I get it to append the items into the 2nd dropdown when additional items are selected in the first?  Many thanks.

[edit]Frustratingly I can't get it working on jsfiddle but I'll link the code hoping it still makes sense. Not sure if it's because it contains

```
 php?
```

:- http://jsfiddle.net/m1ugpb4o/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the original code link ([Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection))

Had to change this bit:-

```
  function updateSubCats(){
    var catSelect = this;
    var catid = this.value;


    var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
    subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
      subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
    }
```

to this:-

```
  function updateSubCats(){
    var catSelect = this;
    var catid = this.value;
    var testSelectionArray = new Array();

for(var j = 0; j < this.options.length; j++) {
      if (this.options[j].selected) {
           testSelectionArray.push(this.options[j].value); 
       }
}

    var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
    subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    var k=0;
    for(var i = 0; i < testSelectionArray.length; i++){
      catid = testSelectionArray[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < subcats[catid].length; j++){
            subcatSelect.options[k++] = new Option(subcats[catid][j].val,subcats[catid][j].id);
        }        
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery Change - http://api.jquery.com/change/

and in the event handler have your ajax request to populate the second multiselect

edit:
comment with the code and ill update how to do it. (use jsfiddle)

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look at the jQuery change.  I've added my code although I'm even having trouble with jsfiddle!

Comment: You can't use php on jsfiddle, for examples sake lets try to take the php out and just put filler values in thats taken from the db :) - isolate the problem

Comment: link is in main post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm after.  I've got some code working to demonstrate what the problem is (although this code has some additional problems of it's own).
http://jsfiddle.net/m1ugpb4o/19/
If I select a number in the first column the 2nd dropdown updates to show the values that have that id in the 2nd array.  The problem is if I multi select from the numbers column I want it to show all of the corresponding 'AOCs' but it just updates for the last one selected