# 1 out of 3 dropdown list creating conflict using mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select, foreign-keys

Ok so here are the tables I have:

```
departments                                         associates
+--------+------------------+--------------+        +---------+------------------+-----------+------------+
| dep_id | dep_name         | date_added   |        | asso_id | asso_name        | dep_id    | date_added |
+--------+------------------+--------------+        +---------+------------------+-----------+------------+
|  1     | Pick a Department| Date         |        |   1     | A Associate      | 2         |  Date      |
|  2     | Department A     | Date         |        |   2     | B Associate      | 3         |  Date      |
|  3     | Department B     | Date         |        |   3     | C Associate      | 4         |  Date      |
|  4     | Department C     | Date         |        |   4     | D Associate      | 5         |  Date      |
|  5     | Department D     | Date         |        |   5     | A Associate 2    | 2         |  Date      |
+--------+------------------+--------------+        +---------+------------------+-----------+------------+

key_list                                    key_log
+--------+------------+--------------+      +------+--------------+------------+-------------+----------------+
| key_id | key_name   | date_added   |      | id   | key_assigned | key_status | assigned_to | assigned_by    |
+--------+------------+--------------+      +------+--------------+------------+-------------+----------------+
|  1     |  Key 1     | Date         |      |  1   |    Key 1     | 0          | A Associate | logged in name |
|  2     |  Key 2     | Date         |      |  2   |    Key 4     | 0          | B Associate | logged in name |
|  3     |  Key 3     | Date         |      |      |              |            |             |                |
|  4     |  Key 4     | Date         |      |      |              |            |             |                |
|  5     |  Key 5     | Date         |      |      |              |            |             |                |
+--------+------------+--------------+      +------+--------------+------------+-------------+----------------+
```

So I'm trying to create a key log where I can store key names and associate names, and if the key was logged out or in.  My first issue came when trying to link dropdown menus for departments and associates.  I learned that you don't put comas for joins and someone suggested to just go ahead and use multiple querys.
So after some research I went about it this way:

```
<?php
$dbhost_name = "localhost"; 
$database = "db_name";
$username = "user_name";    
$password = "password";

try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
self.location='dd.php?cat=' + val ;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<?Php

@$cat=$_GET['cat']; // Use this line or below line if register_global is off
if(strlen($cat) > 0 and !is_numeric($cat)){ // to check if $cat is numeric data or not. 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
$quer3="SELECT DISTINCT key_name, key_id FROM key_iv order by key_name";

$quer2="SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"; 

if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
$quer="SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"; 
}else{$quer="SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory order by subcategory"; } 

echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd-check.php'>";
    //   Starting of first drop down
echo "<select name=key_names><option value=''>Select Key</option>"; // list box select command

foreach ($dbo->query($quer3) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row

echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[key_name]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 

}

 echo "</select>";// Closing of list box


echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $noticia2) {
if($noticia2['cat_id']==@$cat){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";
// This will end the first drop down list

//     Starting of second drop downlist 
echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer) as $noticia) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcategory]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
//  This will end the second drop down list 

echo "<input type=submit value=Submit>";
echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem with this is that when you select a key, and after select a department, the key originally selected gets reset and you have to go back and select the key again.  You might say o well just place the keys drop down at the end.  Well my intention is later to be able to select a key and with ajax or php check if the key status of that key is 0 (logged out) or 1 (logged back in), if it's on status 0, automatically select the radio button for status 1, and vise versa.

After this I did more research and found this [Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection) and so decided to go with this approach:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'carlos', 'Security5', 'testing');
$query = "SELECT dep_id, dep_name FROM department";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $categories[] = array("id" => $row['dep_id'], "val" => $row['dep_name']);
  }

  $query = "SELECT ass_id, dep_id, ass_name FROM associates";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $subcats[$row['dep_id']][] = array("id" => $row['ass_id'], "val" => $row['ass_name']);
  }

  $jsonCats = json_encode($categories);
  $jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);


?>
<!docytpe html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      <?php
        echo "var categories = $jsonCats; \n";
        echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
      ?>
      function loadCategories(){
        var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
        select.onchange = updateSubCats;
        for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].id);          
        }
      }
      function updateSubCats(){
        var catSelect = this;
        var catid = this.value;
        var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
        subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
        for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
          subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload='loadCategories()'>
  <?php
    $quer3="SELECT DISTINCT key_name, key_id FROM key_list order by key_name";
  echo "<select name=key_names><option value=''>Select Key</option>"; // list box select command

foreach ($dbo->query($quer3) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row

echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[key_name]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 

}

 echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
 ?>

  <select id='categoriesSelect'>
    </select>

    <select id='subcatsSelect'>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem with this is again when I place the first drop down before the other two, the other two don't work, and in this case completely disappear.  When I place it after the two drop downs, everything works.  I know, why am I not placing it after to fix it.  Well like I said before, I need this to work for specifically adding other functionality later.  Than and I refuse to accept that this can't be done.  Can anyone tell me why this is not working for either method, and for that matter which is the better method.

Comment: ***You may want to change your password ASAP, Carlos, because you accidentally pasted it near the top of your second example :) You should probably pick a more secure one, too. https://pwqgen.herokuapp.com/ creates easy to remember and fairly secure passwords.***

Comment: Thanks @JonKloske I will do that for sure, and thanks for the website.  I'm not too worried about this one as I am using mamp on my local system for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your second attempt is you get key_name and key_id from your query, but where you write out the values in the options you refer to key_name and id (not key_id):

```
<?php
    $quer3="SELECT DISTINCT key_name, key_id FROM key_list order by key_name";
    echo "<select name=key_names><option value=''>Select Key</option>"; // list box select command
    foreach ($dbo->query($quer3) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[key_name]</option>"; 
        /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
    }
    echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
?>
```

So, fixing that up (and the lack of quotes around names, and lack of escaping of data onto HTML):

```
<?php
    $querykeys = "SELECT DISTINCT key_name, key_id FROM key_list order by key_name";
    printf("<select name='key_names'>\n");
    printf("<option value=''>Select Key</option>\n");
    foreach ($dbo->query($querykeys) as $row) {
        printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",
            htmlentities($row['key_id'], ENT_QUOTES),
            htmlentities($row['key_name'], ENT_QUOTES)
        );
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response Jon, I was researching printf vs echo, and I was looking into htmlentities and when to use them.  I've utilized your answer and it works.  I also figured out why my second approach had problems when I placed the drop down at the beginning.  Somehow my query $db had an extra letter, so instead of it being $db it was $dbo and that caused a hell of a lot of confusion.  Anyhow, my next mission is creating an entry for storing the information every time a key gets logged out to an associate, and checking to see if key is already out.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries, hopefully the above has helped more broadly, even if the original problem was a typo! :) Re the checking out - if you don't care about history, simply having a nullable "checkedOutBy" field is probably the easiest way to go. If you do care about history, you can just have another table with a keyid, checkedoutby, checkoutdate, and checkindate. To check if a key is available, make sure it has no entries with a null checkindate in that second table (which you can do with a left join, group by keyid, and SUM(chekindate IS NULL) AS outstanding, and HAVING outstanding = 0.