# Dynamic Dropdown Menu [PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a two dropdown that are dynamics, by selecting an option, it changes the other one, just like the Country and Cities examples we see in websites nowadays, but in my case, I want by selecting a Store, it shows all the franquises. I don't know why it's not working.

> Here's the code:

```
<div class="row wow fadeInRight">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
            <form action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label id="drops-labels"><b id="centraliza-txt">Store</b></label>
                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Choose a Store">
                        <?php echo "<select class='form-control input-sm' name='store' id='store-list' onChange='pickFranch(this.value)'>";
                                  echo "<option value='0'>---Select---</option>";
                                        while($dadosRedes = mysql_fetch_array($buscarDadosSuperv)) {
                                            echo "<option value='".$dadosRedes['Store']."'>".$dadosRedes['Store']."</option>";
                                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                        </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
        <label id="drops-labels"><b id="centraliza-txt">Franchise</b></label>
            <select name="franch" id="franch-list" class='form-control input-sm'">
                <option value="0">---Select---</option>
            </select>   
</div>


<script>
        function pickFranch(val) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxPickStore.php",
            data: // i dont know what to put here
            success: function(data){
            $("#lojas-list").html(data);
                        }
            });
            }
</script>
```

> AjaxPickStore.php

```
<?php session_start();

require_once("connect.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["store_id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT Loja FROM indicadores_rv_m1 WHERE store = '".$_POST['store_id']."' and Supervisor = '".$_SESSION['usuarioNome']."'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
    <option value="0">---Select---</option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $franch) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $franch["franch"]; ?>"><?php echo $franch["franch"];?></option>
<?php
    }
}

?>
```

I barely know Ajax, so if you could explain the synthax also, it'd help me a lot!

Ty

Comment: ajax is a communications protocol. it's basically just http. that's it. there is no real "syntax" at the code level. if you mean the jquery .ajax(), then here's the syntax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection)