# how to get id categories when parent category is being updated in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm sorry my english is bad. I would like to update when I get a parent category id category that matches the database and inserted into the select menu. look image bellow :

[click my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4DwM.png)

My database is :

```
==========================================
kat_id | parent_kategori |    kategori   |
==========================================
1      |     0           | wanita        |
2      |     1           | sandal wanita |
3      |     1           | sepatu wanita |
```

my view is :

```
<div class="input group">
        <label>Kategori :</label>
        <input type="text" name="kat" class="form-control" id="kat" placeholder="Nama Kategori" value="<?php echo $updatedata['kategori'];?>" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id_kat" value="<?php echo $updatedata['kat_id'];?>" required>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="input group">
        <label>Parent kategori :</label>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('parent',$jabatan,$updatedata['kat_id']); ?>
        <br>
    </div>
```

My controller is :

```
$update = $this->kategori_adm->get_categorie($id);
    $update = $this->kategori_adm->ambil_data_employee($id);

    $dd_jabatan = array();
    foreach ($this->kategori_adm->master_jabatan() as $data_jabatan) 
    {
    $dd_jabatan[$data_jabatan['kat_id']] = $data_jabatan['kategori'];
    }

    $this->data['jabatan']=$dd_jabatan;
    $this->data['updatedata'] = $update;

    $this->load->view('user_log_as_admin/header');
    $this->load->view('user_log_as_admin/kategori/edit',$this->data);
    $this->load->view('user_log_as_admin/footer');
```

and My Model is

```
class kategori_adm extends CI_Model{

function master_jabatan(){
$this->db->order_by('kat_id');
$sql_jabatan=$this->db->get('kategori');
if($sql_jabatan->num_rows()>0){
    return $sql_jabatan->result_array();
    }
}

function ambil_data_employee($id){
$this->db->where('kat_id', array('parent_kategori' => 0));
$sql_employee=$this->db->get('kategori');
if($sql_employee->num_rows()>0){
        return $sql_employee->row_array();
    }
}

function get_categorie($id){
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE kat_id='$id'");
  return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume this is the table:

```
+----+----------------+-----------------+
| id | category_name  | parent_category |
+----+----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | Main           | 0               |
+----+----------------+-----------------+
| 2  | Under Main     | 1               |
+----+----------------+-----------------+
| 3  | Under Main too | 1               |
+----+----------------+-----------------+
```

then select all Categories that have `parent_category = 0`, you can use AJAX to get all the categories with `parent_category` is equal to the selected category's ID.

Try this:
[Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection)

Comment: how the script should be. I am new to CodeIgniter

Comment: Thankyou sir. alkhamdulillah