# 2 drop-down menu related by a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I currently have 2 drop-down menus that populate via a MySQL database.
My database is as following (a simplified version obviously) :

```
+--------+--------+
|Choice1 | Choice2|
+--------+--------+
| A      | A1     |
| A      | A2     |
| B      | B1     |
| B      | B2     | 
+--------+--------+
```

The user has to choose between A and B for the first drop-down menu and the second will update (example : user chose A on the first drop-down menu so the second drop-down menu will let him choose between A1 and A2).
How can I do this ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: show your attempt! where is your code?

Comment: just a clue: i see 2 main ways here: either create all the dropdowns and hide/show them depending on results or use the same dropdown that you update between each choice (sorry, a very general clue, i won't write all this code for you)

Comment: Are you talking about a drop-down menu or a combo box (ie. type of form field)? If the later, there are plenty of examples for a cascading combo-box that uses AJAX to populate the 2nd combo-box when the 1st combo-box value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys ! 
[Best option I found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11636698/7346862)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using Jquery and Ajax. This is a simple code snippet to achieve what you want.

First, inside your index.php:

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".choice1").change(function(){
        var choice1 = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'choice1=' + choice1;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "choice2.php", 
            // You can edit choice2.php for other filename you want
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $(".choice2").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>

Choice1 :
<select name="choice1" class="choice1">
    <option selected="selected">--Select Choice1--</option>
    <?php
        include('db.php');

        $sql= "SELECT DISTINCT Choice1 FROM table_test"; 
        // You should edit table_test for your table name

        $result = mysqli_query($con ,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $choice1 = $row['Choice1'];
            echo '<option value="'.$choice1.'">'.$choice1.'</option>';
        } 
    ?>
</select> 
<br/><br/>

Choice2 :
<select name="choice2" class="choice2">
    <option selected="selected">--Select Choice2--</option>
</select>
```

Then inside your second file. I called it choice2.php:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['choice1']){
    $choice1 = $_POST['choice1'];
    $sql= "SELECT Choice2 FROM table_test WHERE Choice1='$choice1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con ,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $choice2 = $row['Choice2'];
        echo '<option value="'.$choice2.'">'.$choice2.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Then to connect to the database you can use this code snippet. I called this file db.php.

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_test"); 
// You should edit database_test with your database name
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```