# HTML PHP use input type with an IF statement?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm still learning from scratch.
I want to input text based on how the user answers the previous record.

So based on the option they select... I want to enter the status under my "Status" record.

In other words, if the user chooses 2 on the drop down I want status (input hidden) to be filled with the word "Open".
If the user chooses -2, id like Status to be filled with "Closed"

Only have the basic below so far.

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="Open">
```

My question is how do i achieve what im trying to achieve because im lost.

CURRENTLY TRYING

```
 $status = $_POST['status'];
 $result = $_POST['result'];
$result = $_POST['result'] ?? 0;
        $statuses = [
        '-3' => 'Closed',
        '-2' => 'Closed',
        '1' => 'Open',
        '2' => 'Big',
        '3' => 'Bigger',
          ];
          $status = $statuses[$result];
```

IN MY PHP SECTION ABOVE MY QUERY..

```
              <select name="result">
                  <option value="-3">-3</option>
                  <option value="-2">-2</option> 
                  <option value="-1">-1</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>  
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>  
                </select>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate another select dropdown from database based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636293/populate-another-select-dropdown-from-database-based-on-dropdown-selection)

Comment: updated it.
any help would help!

Comment: does Status is column name in DB ?

Comment: What have you tried? This also sounds more like a JavaScript question than a PHP question

Comment: Yes @Krish named "status" and the db is ready

Comment: @j08691 Perhaps thats my problem, i have no idea what to do next or if its possible

Comment: @CarlosDanger set value to Options and form submission you can get them

Comment: @Krish bare with me, still a beginner.. on my 2nd statement, set my value to the options... and what...?

Comment: Hey @Anthony Weener (CarlosDanger), what about statuses `0`, `1`, `-3`...?

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai glad ya caught on, The rest i can figure out, just wanted to get the logic.

Comment: Can anyone else help me? currently getting a " syntax error, unexpected '?'"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP or JS.

Update your HTML so the  have values, for example:

```
<select name="result">
  <option value="-3">-3</option>
```

PHP

User selects `result` and submits the form. then:

```
<?php
$result = $_POST['result'] ?? 0;
$statuses = [
    ...
    '-2' => 'Closed',
    '2' => 'Open',
];
$status = $statuses[$result];
// and save to Database
```

JS/jQuery

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=result]', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == -2){
        $('input[name=status]').val('Closed');
    }
    if (val == 2){
        $('input[name=status]').val('Open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! let me test quickly!

Comment: alright so..   i have _____$status = $_POST['status'];____and____  $result = $_POST['result']; ________ i have the INSERT INTO query where status will go into $status and result will go into $result... result is working great with my option statement above..

Comment: Ok, i updated my original post, clearly im making a mess.. shouldnt i not be doing php again in my html section?

Comment: Ok, so i made the changes, but im getting an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' "

Comment: Unamata.. Sheit, any more help you can provide? im in over my head at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding the question correctly, but I believe this would be better solved using Javascript than PHP.  The reason being that because PHP is a server-side language, the form would have to be submitted before you could change the input (unless you are using AJAX which would be a combination of PHP and Javascript).

Javascript is a client side language and could do what you are looking for.  Using jQuery:

```
$("select[name='result']").on('change', function() {
    var chosenOption = $("select[name='result'] option:selected").text();
    var newText = (chosenOption < 0) ? "Closed" : "Open";
    $("input[name='status']").val(newText);
});
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle if you want to see how it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/turtlechief/b0z2fyfx/